# Generic Filter for enum

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Following is my class

```
public final class Test {
enum Animal {DOG,CAT};
enum COLOR {RED,YELLOW};

class Meaningless {
    String animal,color;
}
public void filter(List<Meaningless> meaninglesses){
    meaninglesses.stream()
            .filter(meaningless -> {
                try {
                    Animal.valueOf(meaningless.animal);
                    return true;
                }catch(Exception e){
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .filter(meaningless -> {
                try {
                    COLOR.valueOf(meaningless.color);
                    return true;
                }catch(Exception e){
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

}

The 2 iterations of `filter` methods essentially filters out the invalid enum types. How can I remove the code duplication from this ? The check should be generic enough so that I dont have to change the `isValidEnum` when there is a new `enum` introduced.

Ideally I would like to do something like

```
 meaninglesses.stream()
            .filter(meaningless -> isValidEnum(meaningless.animal,Animal.class))
            .filter(meaningless -> isValidEnum(meaningless.color,COLOR.class))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following utility method should do the trick here,

```
public static <E extends Enum<E>> boolean validateEnum(Class<E> clazz, String s) {
    return EnumSet.allOf(clazz).stream().anyMatch(e -> e.name().equals(s));
}
```

And here's how your client code looks in practice,

```
boolean isValid = validateEnum(Animal.class, "DOG");
```

Finally, putting it back to your context, it should be something like this.

```
meaninglesses.stream()
    .filter(meaningless -> validateEnum(Animal.class, meaningless.animal))
    .filter(meaningless -> validateEnum(COLOR.class, meaningless.color))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: With Guava you can check `Enums.getIfPresent(clazz, s).isPresent()`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of reinventing the wheel, you can simply go with Apache Common EnumUtils `isValidEnum(Class<E> enumClass,String enumName)`

Also,  `isValidEnumIgnoreCase(Class<E> enumClass,String enumName)` can be used to check if you need case-insensitivity.

Docs [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/EnumUtils.html#isValidEnum-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String-)